# I want to send video to video view in another activity but crashs

Tags: android

in my adapter

```
 holder.animPlayer.setVideoURI(mAnmList.get(position).getVideourl());
```

in mainActivity

```
intentAnimation.putExtra("Video", animationItem.getVideourl());
```

in getExtraActivity

```
Intent playVideo = getIntent();
   moviePlayer = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
   Uri video = Uri.parse(playVideo.getStringExtra("Video"));
   moviePlayer.setVideoURI(video);

    moviePlayer = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(moviePlayer);
   moviePlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
   moviePlayer.requestFocus();
   moviePlayer.start();
```

my level is beginner, help

Comment: Please share crash log from logcat?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:476)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:438)

Comment: at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.iniViews(MovieDetails.java:92)
        at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onCreate(MovieDetails.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7015)

Comment: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7006)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: From crash it seems like your extra which is sent is null. So, animationItem.getVideourl() might have null value in it. Can you confirm this? Or share the code how you are sending extra with intent?